# Create AVD with Target Google APIs Level 23

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-virtual-device

I am trying to create AVD with target Google API - Level 23, But when I select target CPU/ABI says "No System images installed for this target".
I have downloaded all the required packages.
I also found an answer at StackOverflow, that copy all the content of 
"C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-24\default"
To
"C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-24/"
I did that but did not get any benefit.
Please have a look on attached files and suggest any solution.
I am using windows 8 32-bit, I also tried with windows 8.1 64bit but the problem was same.

[image: AVD and packages]

[image: Packages Extra]

Comment: Did you try deleting the packages and installing them again ?

Comment: Yes, I did it two times.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I also have this issue, even though I'm using MacOS 10.12

Comment: Nevermind, for API Level 23 there was only Nexus Galaxy and Nexux S that supported Google APIs Intel Atom.